# Pass stdin to Process (e.g. to enabled sudo)

Tags: swift

I am creating a Swift package that has an executable that will run commands via `Process`. Some of these commands will require user input, such as `sudo`.

How can I ensure that the commands output is shown to the user, and also allow them to interact with the commands, such as typing in their password for `sudo`?

I have a few ways of running the command, which all fail in different ways:

```swift
public func run(_ command: [String]) throws {
    try Process.run(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/env"), arguments: command) { process in
        print("Process terminated", process)
    }
}
```

Fails without user input:

```
Password:
sudo: unable to read password: Input/output error
```

I've also tried:

```swift
public func run(_ command: [String]) throws {
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    process.arguments = command

    let standardError = Pipe()
    process.standardError = standardError

    print("Running \(command.joined(separator: " "))")

    try process.run()
    process.waitUntilExit()

    if process.terminationStatus != 0 {
        let errorData = standardError.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let error = String(data: errorData, encoding: .utf8)!
        throw CommandError(message: error, exitCode: process.terminationStatus)
    }
}
```

which will output `Running sudo [command...]` and stall until ctrl+C is pressed, at which point the process exits and `Password:` is output:

```
Running sudo [command...]
^CPassword:
```

Not setting `process.standardError` does the same, but outputs:

```
Running sudo [command...]
^CPassword:
sudo: unable to read password: Input/output error
```

I've come across similar questions asking about running commands with `sudo` via a GUI application, but I am trying to do this via an executable.

I'm assuming I need to pass `stdin` somehow, but the documentation for `standardInput` on `Process` states `If this method isn’t used, the standard input is inherited from the process that created the receiver` so I'm not sure why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out in kotlin so i hope this helps someone and translates to swift. So i wanted users to be able to enter a terminal command and i'd run the process on their behalf.  If they entered a sudo command i'd need to prompt for a password and then continue with their command providing the password to sudo.  The trick was piping it in with the -k and -S switched:

```
    when {
      
        input.startsWith("sudo ") -> {
            
            val password = "12345" //just like my luggage!
         
            val cmd = arrayOf("/bin/bash", "-c", "echo '$password' | ${input.replace("sudo", "sudo -k -S")}")

            val proc = rt.exec(commands, emptyArray())

            val stdInput = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(proc.inputStream))
        }
       
    }
```